# Core Data insert objects in NSOperation and sync

Tags: objective-c, core-data, concurrency, nsoperation

I'm saving objects from network response in `NSOperation`. As I understand for merge MOC's changes from background threads to main I can use `mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification` or `performBlock` with parent context.

What should I prefer to use `mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification` or `performBlock`?
What are the pros and cons of each merge method?

`NSOperation` executed in background context. So when I call `performBlock` will be created new thread or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Searching answer on my question I found [Concurrent Core Data Stacks Performance](http://floriankugler.com/blog/2013/4/29/concurrent-core-data-stack-performance-shootout) article. This article answer that if you user old core data stack with sync data using `mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification` method you get better performance.
Also I found apple example [ThreadedCoreData](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/ThreadedCoreData/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010723). In this example they still using sync with `mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification`.

So answer on my question is if you carry on performance you should use `mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification` if you what simpler realization you should use nested contexts.

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends very much on whether your background MOC has the main MOC as a parent.

You only need to use `performBlock` if you are using MOCs with private/main queue concurrency.

And if you are, to get commands executed in the corresponding correct queue, you'd use `performBlock`.

So even if you have to use `mergeChanges`-- and you don't have to with child contexts-- you would nest `mergeChanges` in a `performBlock`!  But the reason you don't have to with a child context is because your "background thread" MOC <strike>should</strike> could be a child of the main thread MOC.   So all you have to do is `save` the child to merge changes into the parent.  (Note that the parent also needs to be saved)

So to get back to the question:

- `mergeChanges` if you're **not** pushing changes from child to parent MOC with a save in the child
- use `performBlock` everywhere but on operations on the mainQueueMOC on the main thread if you have using multiple MOCs with different concurrency types

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if two methods you mentioned provide equivalent functionality: you use `performBlock` to perform random code on the tread of the receiver managed object context. And you use `mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification` to process `NSNotification` from another context save. If I got it right up to here, your only chose is the latter.

Potentially you can create a child context within `NSOperation`, saved data from child context propagates into parent context automatically.

To elaborate further, you would use `performBlock` to modify parent's managed objects from the background - it basically dispatches you to the thread of the managed object context to allow perform operations in a safe manner

Comment: Parent-child contexts provide the equivalent of `mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification`. Parent-child contexts require the use of queue confinement, and thus `performBlock:`. So the question is on the right track.