# Creating deep copy of a CoreData datamodel programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I know this is strange and horrible, but it's legacy code. I need to do the following as a workaround:

We are updating `CoreData` with a `SQL` database from an API endpoint. We then loop through this SQL database and insert it in its entirety into `CoreData`. Unfortunately, while we do this process, it literally deletes the data of the `CoreData` DB that correspond to the data we get. This process can take up to 3.5 minutes on an iPhone 4 and this also means a user can experience a crash.

As a suggested fix without us having to strip out CoreData, I need to create an identical `CoreData datamodel`. When I detect an update, I'll update the backup `datamodel` and use the original one until the update is done. Then I'll switch the `NSManagedObjectContext` to be the updated datasource. I'll then use the original `datamodel` for the next update, and so on.

What's the easiest way to loop through a `datamodel` in full and copy it to another `datamodel`?

Comment: Filesystem operation to copy the store and build a new stack from the PSC on up through your MOC.

Comment: It's as easy as doing a `[NSFileManager] copyItemAtURL toURL` and creating a new PSC with the new sqlite db? I'll try this right now, thanks!

Comment: If I were certain, it'd be an answer.. but it's what I'd try first.  The fancier way is create a temporary context for either the GUI or the download and merge changes, but if you don't need to persist anything the user does in those 3.5 minutes, you *can* just have two PSCs and two stores on disk, and discard the old one when you have the new one ready.

Comment: I'm actually implementing a hybrid of using two PSCs/stores on disk but also writing manual code to copy over a subset of entities + their relationships over. Found out that we do need to persist some of the user actions within the 3.5 minutes so unfortunately won't be able to use the Filesystem operation. But it did help me to realize I could use just one datamodel and use two simultaneous PSC/MOC

Comment: *"...it literally deletes the tables of the CoreData DB that correspond to the data we get."* Having a little trouble understanding how or why that would happen.

Comment: @TomHarrington How: Simple! A for loop over the NSManagedObjects in a NSFetchREquest for an Entity with [self.context delegeObject:managedObject]. Technically the table schema is still there but all the rows are gone, bad wording on my part. As for why: bad contractors.

Comment: Now sounds like you'd be better served by a mergeChangesFromContextSave and choosing the right merge policies.  And you probably want one store and one PSC. Just multiple MOCs.

Comment: [This article](http://floriankugler.com/blog/2013/5/11/backstage-with-nested-managed-object-contexts) and [This article](http://www.cocoanetics.com/2012/07/multi-context-coredata/) are good reading.  And here's a [recent answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23740597/core-data-insert-objects-in-nsoperation-and-sync/23746952#23746952) where I try to address this sort of thing.

Comment: @stevesliva Thanks - I'm currently trying two different methods. One with the parent-child that you showed but for some reason deletes on the MOC show up immediately but not insertions (have to reboot the app). I'm also trying with 2 MOC/PSC/MOM with separate datamodels but that leads to infinite memory allocation until it crashes when I read/write to two different MOC simultaneously. I'll let you know if I figure out a solution

Comment: I'm finding parent-child not all that great vs explicitly merging.  You might try a temp privateQueue MOC for download with the same PSC, catch the save and merge the changes into the main MOC after the the temp MOC saves.   If your two PSCs are trying to write the same store, I can see a crash.  But if they're truly writing different stores, they shouldn't care about each other.   Also, semantically, the *model* going to be the same everywhere.